# Form not passing variables php

Tags: php, html, forms

I've made a simple form to deleting entries in a table. When I click the submit button my variables aren't populating. Could someone please suggest why? Here's the html code:

```
<tr class="tr">
   <td class="td">2</td>
   <td class="td">01/05/2017</td>
   <td class="td">1152</td>
   <td class="td">1270</td>
   <td class="td">1125</td>
   <td class="td">855</td>
   <td class="td">1078</td>
   <td class="td">865</td>
   <td class="td">1730</td>
   <td class="td">1255</td>
   <td class="td">
      <form action="delete.php" "method="post">
         <input type="hidden" value="2" name="id">
         <input type="hidden" value="zjl1nl_asia" name="region">
         <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="delete_button">
      </form>
   </td>
</tr>
```

and the receiving php

```
<?php
function secure($var){
    $var = stripslashes($var);
    $var = strip_tags($var);
    $var = htmlentities($var);
    return $var;
}
    //Connect to database
    $hn = "localhost";
    $db = "XXXX";
    $un = "XXXX";
    $pw = "XXXX";

    $conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
    }

$id = secure($_POST['id']);
$region = secure($_POST['region']);

echo "<p>id: $id<br>region: $region</p>";

$query = "DELETE FROM $region WHERE id=$id";
echo $query."<br>";
$result = $conn -> query($query);
if(!$result) die ("Error: ".$conn->error);

$conn->close(); 

?>
```

When I echo the variables to screen they show no values. Looking in the address bar however I can see for example: 
www.example.com/add/delete.php?id=6&region=zjl1nl_asia

Does anyone know why the variables aren't populating?

Comment: Variables in the url are $_GET variables not $_POST variables, try using $_REQUEST['id'] just to see if that gets the value you expect. If it does you need to do some tidying up and make sure your code is sending the variables in the way you expect

Comment: There is a typo in this line - `<form action="delete.php" "method="post">` See the extra quote before `method`? Remove it and it should work fine.

Comment: remove extra double quote before method

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj nice spot

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj thanks, wells spotted. that's now tested and working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error in this line of your code.

```
<form action="delete.php" "method="post">
```

Replace it with

```
<form action="delete.php" method="post">
```

Now it should work fine.

Comment: While this is a perfectly good spot of a bad syntax, this is the sort of error that the OPs IDE should be notifying them about! Is Jamie Moffat writing his code in Windows Notepad?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. IDE should be notifying the user about this kind of errors. There are a lot of Editors that do this, almost all of them. This is so basic.

Comment: There's a very good IDE that spots all sorts of errors (mostly minor) in Life, this IDE is popularly called "***wife***". I'd recommend one for just about anyone `:-D`